# querybuilder query define parameter in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, selectquerybuilder

when i define a parameter in the given section its give me error that  this "tt" parameter  is undefine. i do not know what is the problem. it give me this error

Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::$SELECT u1.unitid, m1.id FROM ApiMapBundle:Mappaths m1 INNER JOIN ApiMapBundle:Unitids u1 WITH m1.refUnitids2 = u1.id OR m1.refUnitids1 = u1.id WHERE m1.id=:tt

```
             $cn=2;
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

            $query = $qb->select('u1.unitid','m1.id')
                    ->from('ApiMapBundle:Mappaths', 'm1')
                    ->join('ApiMapBundle:Unitids', 'u1', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->orX('m1.refUnitids2 = u1.id', 'm1.refUnitids1 = u1.id'))
                    ->andWhere('m1.id=:tt')
                     ->$qb->setParameter('tt', $cn)
                    ->getQuery()

                    ->getResult();
           return $query;
```

any idea?

Comment: try removing the duplicate '->$gb' from the setParameter row

Comment: thanks buddy ya its fine now ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `->$qb` from `->$qb->setParameter('tt', $cn)`